# Completing the square to find if quadratic form is positive definite.

Tags: polynomials, quadratic-forms, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have the quadratic form

$$g=x_1^2+6x_2^2+8x_3^2-4x_1x_2-6x_1x_3-x_2x_3$$

I have problems completing the square. I tried to rewrite the expression as follows

$$g=x_1^2-4x_1x_2+6x_2^2-x_2x_3+8x_3^2$$

Hence,

$$((x_1-2{x_2})^2 -(2x_2)^2) + 6 \left( x_2-\frac{x_3}{12} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{x_3}{2} \right)^2 + 8x_3^2$$

Can I do it like this? On complete square calculator, it's said that you cannot complete the square for expression like this. Anyway, the reason I need to complete the square for this expression is because I need to determine whether the given quadratic form is positive definite. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You can always complete the square using Lagrange's Method. In my answer you can see an example of this. Using the form's matrix is also a good method, many times easier.

Answer (score 4):

Construct the coefficient matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1& -2& -3\\ -2& 6& -1/2 \\-3 &-1/2 & 8\end{bmatrix}$$

Find the determinants

$D_1 = |a_{11}| = 1 > 0$

$D_2 = \begin{vmatrix}1&-2 \\ -2&6\end{vmatrix} = 6 -4 =2 > 0$

$D_3 = \det(A) = -177/4 < 0$

> So, the given form is indefinite in nature.

For an nxn matrix if

> $\bullet D_1 , D_2, \cdots D_n>0 \implies$ Positive definite
>
> $\bullet D_1,D_3,D_5\cdots<0 $ and $D_2,D_4,D_6\cdots>0$ or $(-1)^kD_k >0   , \  k =0,1,\cdots n \implies$ Negative definite
>
> $\bullet D_1 , D_2, \cdots D_n \ge0$ or $D_k>0 $  with at least one value zero $\implies$ Positive semi-definite
>
> $\bullet(-1)^kD_k \ge0   , \  k =0,1,\cdots n$ with at least one zero $\implies$ Negative semi-definite
>
> $\bullet$All other cases are indefinite

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $x_2=0$ then the quadratic form $g$ is 
$$x_1^2+8x_3^2-6x_1x_3=(x_1-2x_3)(x_1-4x_3)$$ 
whose sign is indefinite. So $g$ is NOT positive definite.

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot complete the square"? Lagrange's method for completing the square in quadratic forms is based precisely on the fact that you *always* can complete the square.

Comment: But you always can ! Read my answer. It is just Lagrange's method applied. Of course, negative coefficients allowed

Comment: If that were the case then completing the square would be pretty useless in many cases...

Answer (score 3):

Completing the square (Lagrange's Method):

$$x^2+6y^2+8z^2-4xy-6xz-yz=\left(x-(2y+3z)\right)^2-4y^2-12yz-9z^2+6y^2+8z^2-yz$$

$$=\left(x-(2y+3z)\right)^2+2y^2-13yz-z^2=\left(x-(2y+3z)\right)^2+2\left(y-\frac{13}4z\right)^2-\frac{177}8z^2$$

Thus, for example, $\;g(38,\,13,\,4)=-177\cdot2=-354<0\;$ and thus the form isn't positive definite.

BTW, $\;g(1,0,0)=1\;$ , so the form is actually indefinite.

Comment: Yes, completing the square is possible! (+1)

Comment: @DonAntonio Can you explain why did you chose $2y+3z$ a the beginning to form square? Also why the last coefficient to $z^2$ is $\frac{177}{8}$ not $\frac{169}{8}$?
Then I don't uderstand why do you chose such values $g(38,13,4)$? Why if $g(1,0,0)= 1$ is the form indefinite? Would it be also indefinite if $g=(0,1,0)=1$?

Comment: (1) The rule is: take half the coefficient of the linear term to complete square. For example, $\,ax^2+bx=a\left(x^2+\frac bax\right)=a\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}\,$ and etc. In the given quadratic from, the coefficient of $\,x\,$ is$\,-(4x+6z)\,$ , so half this...and etc.

Comment: Also, I chose a vector as simple as I could. With $\,w:=(38,13,4)\,$ we get $\,g(w)<0\;$ . Then, we only need a vector for which its value is negative and thus the form is indefinite (perhaps you need to go over the definition of "definite positive, definite negative, indefinite and etc.)

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you, now I understand about the coefficients. 1) Did you manually by try and error found which value would make the expression zero? 2) What about that coefficient to $z^2$, why it's $\frac{177}{8}$ instead of $\frac{169}{8}$?

Comment: Leva: I chose a vector for which the first two terms will be zero and only the one with negative coefficient remains, And it is $\;\frac{177}8\;$ because we still have to add $\;-z^2\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $H$ is the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives of $g=x^2+6y^2+8z^2-4xy-6xz-yz$

This direction is what "completing the square" produces first:

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 &  -  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 177 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 4 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 4 & 12 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 1 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Dividing  the coefficients of $D$ by two gives
$$ (x-2y-3z)^2 + 2 \left( y - \frac{13}{4} z\right)^2 - \frac{177}{8} z^2 = x^2+6y^2+8z^2-4xy-6xz-yz$$
and is exactly what DonAntonio got

The method actually produces the reverse first:

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 19 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 4 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 4 & 12 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 1 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 &  \frac{ 19 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 177 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 4 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 4 & 12 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 1 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 4 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 4 & 12 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 1 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 &  - 6 \\ 
0 & 4 &  - 13 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 13 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 &  - 13 \\ 
0 &  - 13 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 &  \frac{ 19 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 177 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 19 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 4 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 4 & 12 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 1 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 &  \frac{ 19 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 177 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 &  -  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 177 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 4 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 4 & 12 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 1 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: I am lost as to what you *really* tried to do here, though I suspect is something close to "elementary congruency" or "congruency transformation: carrying on row elementary operations and exactly the same column operations ...etc. until *the symmetric** matrix is diagonalized. The term "Hessian matrix" is known to me from advanced calculus, but I can't see here how it pops up: if you meant the Hessian of $\;g\;$ as function $\;\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R\;$ , then you get a diagonal one and not pretty useful, as far as I can see, matrix, as all the mixed partial derivatives of second order vanish...

Comment: @DonAntonio  $H$ is the Hessian of $g=x^2+6y^2+8z^2-4xy-6xz-yz \; . \;$ Sometimes this is called congruence diagonalization. It tells us the signs of the eigenvalues of $H,$ according to Sylvester's Law of Inertia.  I give a fair amount of detail at  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr   Note that the matrix version $Q^T D Q = H$ is almost exactly what you gave.